# Shape convert to Combo box or other component

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm working on a flash project, the designer designs UI by Flash CS5 and export the UI as swc file, I use Flex to control the data on the UI.

The designer uses shapes for the UI design, it is easy for him to define the colors and background, but I need this shapes more like a component like Combo box, so I can display the data on those shapes.

Is there any easy way to covert shapes to combo box or the similar operations?

Comment: +1 to cancel the anonymous -1

Comment: Thanks Kodiak. Do you know the answer?

Comment: The answer to "Is there any easy way to convert shapes to combo box?" is no. But a correct answer should provide alternative solutions for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex skins are programmatic (AS3 for Flex 3, MXML for Flex 4) so there is no easy way to 
convert a vector design to a component skin.
But you should give a look at this https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex_skins
This may help your designer to create Flex-friendly graphics.